# How can I know if there is a connection between my Surface and Typecover?

Tags: microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-4

My Typecover is not working with my Surface Pro (Both "4" versions)

How can I know if there is a physical connection, and what the problem is?
What is usually the problem on the Surface side when there is a low level problem?

(I have no connection in BIOS-mode, and no LEDs are working)

Comment: The most obvious would be that Windows 8/Windows 10 switches from Tablet mode off.

Comment: in "BIOS mode"?

Comment: The typecover is also backlit, the keys should light up when pressed. One thing to do would be to check in Device Manager, under Keyboards there should be a "Surface Type Cover Filter Device".

Comment: @Olav No; Within Windows